# How to install Pandas to a specific python installation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, path, sys

I am trying to install Pandas in a version of Python that is bundled with an API. In an IDE bundled with the API I run the following:

**Code**

```
import sys
type(sys.path)

for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\HF_AutoCal
```

I have pointed the API to a version of Python3.7, now when I try to import pandas it says error. When I try and install pandas it says it is already satisfied as Pandaas is installed in Python3.8. I cannot point the API to Py3.8 as the API won't work with it, is there a way I can get Pandas and Numpy into the Python3.7?

Comment: Are the paths duplicated as well, with several instances of ```C:\Program Files\... DropWatch\Python\Lib\site-packages```, or does the ```...``` part vary?

Comment: It is not an error to have directories on `sys.path` which do not exist on your system, per se.

Comment: Hi Octavel, the '...' does not vary so I guess they are duplicate instances.